# Why use beforeRouteEnter instead of mounted?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Why does the `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard exist in vue-router? Are there instances where `beforeRouteEnter` will be fired, but `mounted` will not be? If not, in what instance would you prefer using `beforeRouteEnter` to `mounted`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mounted` is a lifecycle hook of any Vue component, it'll always be triggered. The idea of `beforeRouteEnter` or any other lifecycle hook added by the `vue-router` is to allow you to control your application.

For example, let's say that you have a route called `bar` which has a really specific validation logic that only allow the user to enter in it if the previous route was `foo`, you may insert that validation logic inside this hook instead of checking every route change in the global guard.

```
export default {
  name: 'Bar',
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (from.name === 'foo') {
      next(); // Calling next allow the route to proceed
    } else {
      next(false); // Don't allow the navigation
      // or
      next({
        name: 'foo',
        query: {
          from: 'bar'
        }
      }); // Redirect to any desired route as navigation made in $router
    }
  }
}
```